# Problem with parameters with arm_kinematics

Tags: ros, arm-kinematics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear List,

First some specs:

os: ubuntu 10.10
ros version: ros-cturtle-base 1.0.0-s1297419884~maverick
arm_kinematics version: wu-ros-pkg - Revision 40: /stacks/urdf_tools/trunk/arm_kinematics

URDF file i used:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="myfirst">
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</robot>
```

Parameters i configured:

```
$ rosparam set urdf_xml robot_description
$ rosparam set robot_description /home/wouter/ros_packages/urdf_tools/urdf_tutorials/01-myfirst.urdf
$ rosparam set root_name myfirst
$ rosparam set tip_name base_link
$ rosparam set maxIterations 1000
```

Start command used:

$ wouter@wouter-MXC061:~/ros_packages/urdf_tools/urdf_tutorial$ rosrun arm_kinematics arm_kinematics

Error after starting the service:

$ [FATAL] [1298977044.887195523]: GenericIK: No root name found on parameter server

So i looked in arm_kinematics.cpp and i found the following code (line: 101/363):

```
// Get Root and Tip From Parameter Service
if (!nh_private.getParam("root_name", root_name)) {
    ROS_FATAL("GenericIK: No root name found on parameter server");
    return false;
}
```

I don't see how this error could occur, because i defined the parameters. Anyone have any thoughts on this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9247/problem-with-parameters-with-arm_kinematics/) by [Wouter van Teijlingen](https://answers.ros.org/users/77/wouter-van-teijlingen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's getting the root_name from the node parameter server, try to load the parameter like this (replace arm_kinematics by the arm_kinematics node name):

```
rosparam set arm_kinematics/robot_description /home/wouter/ros_packages/urdf_tools/urdf_tutorials/01-myfirst.urdf
```

By the way, you should have at least to links and 1 joint in your model. The root_name should be a link (e.g. "base_link") and the tip_name another link.

Hope this help

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed it, thanks for your pointers. This is the solution:

```
$ rosparam set urdf_xml robot_description
$ rosparam set robot_description /home/wouter/ros_packages/urdf_tools/urdf_tutorial/01-myfirst.urdf
$ rosparam set arm_kinematics/root_name base_link
$ rosparam set arm_kinematics/tip_name base_link
$ rosparam set maxIterations 1000
```

Before you start arm_kinematics run the following command, because it is necessary load the XML file in to robot_description.

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=01-myfirst.urdf
```

Thanks for the help.

---

Originally posted by [Wouter van Teijlingen](https://answers.ros.org/users/77/wouter-van-teijlingen/) with karma: 63 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1